# Why is my code not fitting the correct sersic function?

Tags: python, gaussian, astropy

I am trying to fit the surface brightness profile to a galaxy and I either get an error that states:Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800 or it just doesn't fit the data. Has anyone done this before and could offer help?

My Code:

```
from astropy.io import ascii
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize
from astropy.io import fits
import math

#plate scale for CofC Observatory
f = 3962                #mm
p = 206265./f           # arcsec/mm
p = p * 9.e-6           #arcsec/pix
finalp = p * 20         #pc/pix, sombrero = 97, ngc720 = 105, ngc6946 = 20
finalp = finalp/1000    #kpc

#importing files
data_b = ascii.read('/Users/research/Desktop/Dowd.A/Final/data/NGC6946/ngc6946_b_profile.dat')
data_g = ascii.read('/Users/research/Desktop/Dowd.A/Final/data/NGC6946/ngc6946_g_profile.dat')
data_r = ascii.read('/Users/research/Desktop/Dowd.A/Final/data/NGC6946/ngc6946_r_profile.dat')


#Converting x-axis from pixels to kpc
r_b = data_b['x']*finalp
r_g = data_g['x']*finalp
r_r = data_r['x']*finalp

y_b = data_b['y'] - 412.    #final number is background, different for each filter
y_g = data_g['y'] - 1288.
y_r = data_r['y'] - 1364.

r_b = np.array(r_b)
y_b = np.array(y_b)
r_g = np.array(r_g)
y_g = np.array(y_g)
r_r = np.array(r_r)
y_r = np.array(y_r)

#fitting the model for sersic and exponential
def GaussPoly(r, munaught, beta, n0):
    return munaught * np.exp(-beta*(r/re)**(1/n0))

munaught = 8       #change for each filter 
beta = .001            #change for each filter
r = r_b
n0 = 1.              #1 for spiral and 4 for elliptical
re = r_b[0]

nlfit, nlpcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(GaussPoly, r_b, y_b, p0=[munaught, beta, n0])
munaught, beta, n0 = nlfit

x600 = np.arange(0,10)
fit = GaussPoly(x600, munaught, beta, n0)

plt.plot(x600, fit, color = 'orange')


#commented out filters to see one graph at a time
plt.plot(r_b,y_b, 'b.')
plt.xlabel('Avg Radius (kpc)')
plt.ylabel('Surface Brightness (counts/pixel**2)')
plt.savefig('ngc6946_radial_profile_b')
```

Comment: It is tough to answer, there are many reasons why a fitting method would not converge. And without data it is hard to guess. The function [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) seems to be a wrapper of [leastsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq). You should be able to provide the same keywords, especially `maxfev` to increase the number of calls. Also be sure to start the fitting not far from the optimum. A plot of the raw data, and the initial guess could be useful.

Comment: It might also help to see a plot of your data.  Though all the code you posted for loading and plotting the data is not really relevant to the question either.  Please try to reduce your question to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), possibly including some data that reproduces the issue.  Or like I said at least a plot.  E.g. if your Gaussian has some long tails it may help to cut your fit data off to a few standard deviations

Comment: FWIW Astropy also has a built-in [model fitting package](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/index.html), though most of the algorithms underlying it are from `scipy.optimize` so you might have the same problems.